# Can an Android app get data and interact with other apps that are currently running?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, lastpass

I noticed that several apps like Facebook Messenger and LastPass can show widgets over other apps and even detect elements in those apps and fill input fields. I wonder how this is implemented and what are the limitations.

I'd really appreciate any references you could provide.

I'm new to Android development so please feel free to edit the question if it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: I want to write the app the gets data from other apps.

Comment: As you can see here `You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to share your data with other applications.`, you can only get data from applications that implement their Content Provider. For that you can follow the link I posted and see how, right on the first part, which is by using a `ContentResolver`. I gave you the entire tutorial so you can understand what you are using rather that just using it...